# AndEngine Smooth Finger Follow

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I would like the Sprite to follow my finger smoothly.

The scene is registered for touch events and so far I have this:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    Vector2 characterPosition =  mCharacterSprite.getBody().getPosition();
    float sceneX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
    float charaX = characterPosition.x * 32;
    float sceneY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
    float charaY = characterPosition.y * 32;

    if( Math.abs(sceneX - charaX) < 100 && Math.abs(sceneY - charaY) < 100) {
        mCharacterSprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(0.01f, charaX , sceneX, charaY, sceneY));
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is the sprite always returns to the centre and he moves around the screen randomly insted of following my finger.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this code... it works.
just set the "sprite.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(),pSceneTouchEvent.getY())" in the block, dont even have to register the touchEvent of sprite with the scene.

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) 
{

        sprite.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
    return false;
}
```